# Problem about using turtlebot_arm with "pincher" argument

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using ROS indigo with Ubuntu 13.10, and the phantomx pincher arm. The arbotix version is the newest one (for indigo).

Following this link "https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros/pull/28/files?short_path=04c6e90", I add something like "arm_type:=pincher" after my command. For example: roslaunch turtlebot_arm_moveit_config turtlebot_arm_moveit.launch sim:=false arm_type:=pincher --screen

The good thing is: I got the phantomx pincher model in RViz. But I also got these errors:

[image: image description]

And the planning process was always failed:

[image: image description]

Also, noting that the arm.launch file mentions that it's could be problematic to directly pass the "pincher" arg, ***I also tried changing the argument in the launch file, and the outcome didn't change (I got the same errors***).
Could someone get me out of this problem? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208215/problem-about-using-turtlebot_arm-with-%22pincher%22-argument/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-04-30**:
Hi, if you can see the pitcher arm properly I suppose you are using [this fork](https://github.com/corot/turtlebot_arm) of the code, right? The pitcher arm stuff is not released still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the PhantomX Pincher arm, you will need to use these:

Arbotix fork:     https://github.com/corb555/arbotix_ros

Turtlebot_arm fork:    https://github.com/corot/turtlebot_arm  (as mentioned by Jorge, above)

I think you can't pass the arm type as a parameter as you did above.  You need to set environment variable "TURTLEBOT_ARM1" to pincher.

---

Originally posted by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) with karma: 339 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2015-05-01**:
Thanks for your advice. I replaced my packages with yours. And I changed the  argument "pincher" in the launch file. But I still got these errors. Perhaps my way of setting environment variable "TURTLEBOT_ARM1" is wrong? Thanks for your further help!

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-05-01**:
you shouldnt need to change any of the launch files.  you should do the following before you launch:

```
export TURTLEBOT_ARM1=pincher
```

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2015-05-03**:
Thanks! I solved it.